# Open application on computer using web server and PHP

Tags: php, permissions, xampp, webserver, shell-exec

Hi I'm trying to launch an application on my computer from my phone using a web server and PHP
I'm using XAMPP on mac here is my PHP:

```
<?php echo shell_exec("/Users/gabepersaud/Desktop/test.app 2>&1");?>
```

this returns: "sh: 1: /Users/gabepersaud/Desktop/test.app: not found"

I believe my problem is that the command is executing on the server side and not locally. makdir works and I am able to create new folders on the server. Just not sure how to access local machine

Someone asked a similar question but I was unable to understand the solution: [Run a script on a computer from php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9057076/run-a-script-on-a-computer-from-php)
Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: So you want a web page to be allowed to run an application on your computer.  Not sure if this is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out using just python and flask. os.system allows you to launch applications. pretty cool